# Chrome Extention open multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I built an extension for chrome, I would like to open a new tab when the user clicks on the extension icon.

```
if (result.loginStatus == "loggedOut") {
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: chrome.extension.getURL('login.html') });
        let msg = {
            txt: "hello"
        }
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, msg);
    }
```

When I click on Extention icon multiple the numbers of new tabs like **1>2>4>8...**.
Any ideas how to fixed this

Comment: If you want to send the message to the newly created tab, it should be done differently, see [this answer](/a/54715122) for common solutions.

Comment: So you want to multiple the number of tabs each time icon is clicked?